# Im trying to create a new div on click but for some reason my dom is never updating. Why is this not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unsure what I am doing wrong..If I switch the state to a counter it works, but I need it to be an array of objects to store different values for each div. Not sure why the dom never updates.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

// The parent component
const App = () => {
  const [textBoxDivs, setTextBoxDivs] = useState([]);

  const addNewTextBox = () => {
    const textboxes = textBoxDivs;
    const numOfTextBoxDivs = textBoxDivs.length;
    const newTextBox = { id: `div${numOfTextBoxDivs + 1}` };
    textboxes.push(newTextBox);
    setTextBoxDivs(textboxes);
    console.log(textboxes, "boxes");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => addNewTextBox()}>Click me</button>
      {textBoxDivs.length > 0
        ? textBoxDivs.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index} id={item.id}>
              text
            </div>
          ))
        : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

codeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-water-wf4f5?file=/src/App.js:0-749

Answer (score 3):

Because you are attempting to mutate existing state by pushing a new item to `textBoxDivs`, rather than providing a new state, breaking one of the fundamental rules of React.

Instead of `push`ing to your `textBoxDivs` array, provide a new copy of your state, with the new item inserted:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

// The parent component
const App = () => {
  const [textBoxDivs, setTextBoxDivs] = useState([]);

  const addNewTextBox = () => {
    const numOfTextBoxDivs = textBoxDivs.length;
    const newTextBox = { id: `div${numOfTextBoxDivs + 1}` };

    setTextBoxDivs((textBoxDivs) => ([
        ...textBoxDivs,
        newTextBox
    ]));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => addNewTextBox()}>Click me</button>
      {textBoxDivs.length}
      {textBoxDivs.length > 0
        ? textBoxDivs.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index} id={item.id}>
              text
            </div>
          ))
        : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Reading:**

- [Array spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals)

I should note that there's nothing inherently wrong with using push in this scenario, the issue is that you are pushing to existing state. You could just as easily do

```
// Still creating a new state from the current state
const newTxtBoxDivs = [...textBoxDivs];

newTxtBoxDivs.push(newTextBox);

setTextBoxDivs(newTxtBoxDivs);
```

For the same effect. The key take-away is that `newTxtBoxDivs` does not refer to the same object as `textBoxDivs`, it refers to a copy of it.